# How to create a type guard for a string template literal

Tags: typescript, typeguards

How can you distinguish between multiple template literal string types? If I define

```
type UnionTypeExample =  `${string}_id` | `${string}_username`
```

with

```
x:  UnionTypeExample
```

how can I check if `x` is an id or a username? The temptation is to use some combination of `includes()` and `"string"`, but this does not work with type guarding.

Right now I get errors like

```
Argument of type '`https://${string}` | `${string}_id`' is not assignable to parameter of type '`https://${string}`'.
  Type '`${string}_id`' is not assignable to type '`https://${string}`'.(2345)
```

Code example is below, but this [typescript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgTgGygXigAwBbGGAzgLgHpCASAb12DgEsA7AcwF80BuAKFEigEkARFdOUo0GjAPrUAJqw7hoAQWw0ARgFdgEACpyBtVQFtlEOFAA%20UXgEMNZ2Ilt92nBUupqNAGUtGEABTgA9ngCZGwAkNZUbuoQ%20FB6hsa2Vjbm8AjsjGxsAMYBtJRQGJa0kggQAHIGRiaoABQAbpYIcVWJcACUKAB8UHkFAeUAdAgB9HVo5E0IjHHUuFCW8dXGAIRoHbn5hcWl5SnQ9dNxB13Ivf24gxAjYxNTzbNQ84tQktYQ65uXwEUlZRB0gJGs04ukzhdttdbuNJmRpk8XktVIgvlsCr9dgC%20MDjjxeBC%20lDhqNYQ8ZnMFiVnpI0WwAGaqWg5YDUfJQRRRdwQLw%20OqRFQxOKcwUabSQLqhMLUelQOrOAKygXRGzINVQABECRqGsl4TCWPKbRq-Nc3M2YUYUHCEAQuGgMrlyu5zwxJRyEEVFg%20erCBv%20%20w%20pq5MQtWTCxCgAHVir8XsAMNA8nA4BAWVA4EzWfok4mcgBrKDAALxSwpgIAdyLGHjOnpgX0diQ5hxxagACtVIV0gB%20a1hW3256y%20VyL3OmIodUa4R0egaqAAMkXizNMSGlDLwFwUeoCbqGqwOAIxF1vv9e0BiGDoogXXCVptdugZH7F%20xvBvKrvD7YjHY2TEJoNYLC8FaxjwUAVgEqgIJIUAQAAHpA6YJtAME4OoRYlkY%20DolcJJ3CK368radQAIwdF0kbkc8VLLO0qz4dCpJ1MR3KkQgdS0BAVYHHUVHUYQUAANqaAA8rw8gAJoALp0a87waExlwsURa6eN4ZGHtgeBEIQ9ABGMwx5PoZ5QJGR56cQhnGTcpkKciqLMYR4zsTEnEHpIYwSJI5mRt59C%20Y5tA0qsUBAA) shows the error more clearly.

```
type Url = `https://${string}`;
type ID = `${string}_id`;
type AttributeType = number | Date | Url | ID;
type AttributeLabelProps = {
    attribute: number | Date | Url;
}

const handleNumber = (val: Number) => console.log(`${val}: is a number!`)
const handleDate = (val: Date) => console.log(`${val}: is a date!`)
const handleUrl = (val: Url) => console.log(`${val}: is a url!`)
const handleID = (val: ID) => console.log(`${val}: is an id!`)

function AttributeLabel(attribute: AttributeType) {
    if (typeof attribute === "number") {
        handleNumber(attribute)
    } 
    else if (attribute instanceof Date) {
        handleDate(attribute)
    }
    // What is the correct runtime check to narrow this type from Url | ID to just Url? 
    else if (typeof attribute === "string" && attribute.startsWith("https://")) {
        handleUrl(attribute) // error!
        //        ~~~~~~~~~
        // Argument of type '`https://${string}` | `${string}_id`' is 
        // not assignable to parameter of type '`https://${string}`'.
    } 
    else { 
        handleID(attribute)
        //       ~~~~~~~~~
        // Argument of type '`https://${string}` | `${string}_id`' is 
        // not assignable to parameter of type '`${string}_id`'.

    }
};


//This is what I would expect the output to be:
console.log(AttributeLabel(1)) // 1 is a number!
console.log(AttributeLabel(new Date())) // [TODAY] is a date!
console.log(AttributeLabel("https://google.com")) // https://google.com is a url!
console.log(AttributeLabel("dog_id")) // dog_id is an id!
```

Comment: Use the `is` keyword, like so:
`function isURL(attribute:any): x is Url {return typeof attribute === "string" && attribute.startsWith("https://");}`

Comment: @jcalz Hey stranger! I want to do it at runtime, but the prescribed solution (the one you tried, and I tried) does not work with the current typeguard/error message/type protection/not really sure what you call it. I have attached an image to show what I mean.

Comment: YES. Both of those work. I think the second was specifically what I was trying to do, but either is acceptable.

Comment: I've posted an answer and made the recommended edits to the question.

Comment: As an aside, remember to use the type `number` instead of `Number`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't interpret calling [the `startsWith()` string method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) as a way of [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) it to an appropriate pattern [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html). The [call signature for `startsWith()` in the TypeScript library](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/d3513ee5c4960467c458c5d567437194aa3e828c/src/lib/es2015.core.d.ts#L434) just returns `boolean`, not a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).  This call signature predates the existence of template literal types in TypeScript, and the subsequent suggestion in [microsoft/TypeScript#46958](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46958) to change it to a type guard was declined.  So it's not part of the language, and you'll need to work around it.

---

If you want to see `startsWith()` behave like a type guard in your code base, you can do so by [merging in](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) an appropriate call signature:

```
interface String {
    startsWith<T extends string>(t: T): this is `${T}${string}`;
}
```

And then your code will just work without needing refactoring:

```
function AttributeLabelPlain(attribute: AttributeType) {
    if (typeof attribute === "number") { handleNumber(attribute) }
    else if (attribute instanceof Date) { handleDate(attribute) }
    else if (typeof attribute === "string" && attribute.startsWith("https://")) {
        handleUrl(attribute) // okay
    }
    else { handleID(attribute) } // okay
};
```

Of course you might not want to do this.  The suggestion to do it globally was declined because it makes the behavior of `startsWith()` more complicated for the compiler, and because it can lead to performance problems if the string literal types being considered are [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).

---

Another approach, which is more self-contained, is to refactor your check into its own custom type guard function, so that only the call to that function acts as a type guard instead of every invocation of `startsWith()`.  Like this:

```
function isUrl(x: any): x is Url {
    return typeof x === "string" && x.startsWith("https://");
}

function AttributeLabel(attribute: AttributeType) {
    if (typeof attribute === "number") { handleNumber(attribute) }
    else if (attribute instanceof Date) { handleDate(attribute) }
    else if (isUrl(attribute)) { handleUrl(attribute) } // okay
    else { handleID(attribute) } // okay
};
```

I'd probably do the latter, although you'll need to be careful that the compiler just *believes* that your `isUrl()` is implemented correctly. If you ever change the definition of `Url` then you'll need to remember to change the implementation accordingly; no error message will be issued.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-vsPrXgzEG02W23nqn05AB12Yih8wWTQwC1AAGS7xZ1mJDRXKtUajB1AtYHAEYil4ejvaAxCTuMQGfhOfQeVP7G8N8cw-cIskYdhsmITR+QWF4AHdil+bgoFg5l2V1PVIF9KA+WgZkcHUbCAigIx8HRK4STuWMgLDFs6gARg6LoGTo54qWWdpVjI6FSTqKiQxohA6loCBYMHDQ6kYpjCCgABtTQAHleHkABNABdVjXneDROMubjKKPTxvFo69sDwIhCHoAIxmGPJ9AfKAGRvMziEs6yblsjTkVRLiKPGPiYgEq9JDGCRJHshlgvoULPNoGlVigIA)